# Prettier force white space before and after every balise in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, prettier

I work on a project using Prettier, the project use Nuxt(Vuejs framework).
I see a really weird behaviour about Prettier and the HTML rendered.

---

*If i have a balise (h1,h2,div...) like this:*

```
<h2>I am a too long title and i proc a error</h2>
```

*Prettier want to format them like this:*

```
<h2>
  I am a too long title and i proc a error
</h2>
```

*There is no problem and i like to have this format, but when i inspect the element inside the browser inspector i can see a white space before and after the text.*

```
<h2> I am a too long title and i proc a error </h2>
```

---

This is really unexepected, and really bad too, the only way to solve this i have fund is to not format it with prettier.
But i can't believe this problem is on every project in all world who use Prettier.

https://codepen.io/deeluxe/pen/dyqXZMj -> example with space before and after on the second element.

Comment: If you don't like the format that prettier gives, you will need to use a different tool. Also, the whitespace between the text and the HTML tags are not rendered.

Comment: It's not a style problem but a rendered, the space before/after is rendered and that the big problem for me. (the last element is the rendered html)

Comment: Not before and after (just after it seems) https://codepen.io/evolutionxbox/pen/OJoXOPY

Comment: It's because is not inside a other element like this https://codepen.io/deeluxe/pen/dyqXZMj , you see it on the second exemple

Comment: Even in that example, the second one only renders the end whitespace, even then it doesn't seem to be an issue

Comment: Is the issue just that you don't like the formatting in the _browser inspector_ because you can't really control that and it's not even really the HTML you've written, it's a recreation

Comment: Weird, i have the too white space (windows 10 on chrome latest), and for me it's a issue, i'm pretty sur starting and ended title with space is really bad.
To respond to @HenryWoody, i don't care about the formating, someone pointed a title have white space before and after.
And trying to solve what cause this, i realized it's everywhere on multiple project where the balise is too long and formated by prettier.

Comment: "This is really unexepected, and really bad too" - how is it bad? Functionally it's irrelevant, as leading and trailing whitespace is mostly ignored: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace

Comment: I only talk about seo and i can be wrong obviously.
Whitespace is ignored when is multiple but not if is single, and if you go on any big website you never find a title start with white space, so i concluded this is bad.

You can see ir, the white space is remove, but not at the start or end https://codepen.io/deeluxe/pen/dyqXZMj

Comment: @RaphaelRlt "if you go on any big website you never find a title start with white space" - OK, I just checked some minor websites, like the New York Times and BBC, and yes, I _did_ find plenty of leading and trailing whitespace. I still fail to see what is the problem besides "I don't like it".

Comment: Inside title?
Like i said, i don't have a problem with this ^^'. It's a issue pointed by a tech director like a seo problem. And i just think title started by white space is not seo friendly

Comment: whitespace not a problem for SEO https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12447

Comment: Thanks for the link, i will point that and see what people think!

Comment: You can setup html whitespace sensitivity in the prettier configuration: https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#html-whitespace-sensitivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added already a comment, but I want to also post it as an answer here, because someone else might also have the same question at some point.

In the [prettier options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#html-whitespace-sensitivity) you can configure the `htmlWhitespaceSensitivity` which can have different values. This setting is also used in Vue templates to format the HTML.

The `htmlWhitespaceSensitivity` option can have three values:

### `strict`

Strict sensitivity makes sure, that the whitespace characters within the element are not changed. (If this looks good, is another question)

```html
<h2
  >I am a too long title and i proc a error</h2
>
```

### `ignore`

Prettier would add whitespace if it is needed for the formatting.

```html
<h2>
  I am a too long title and i proc a error
</h2>
```

### `css`

Respect the default whitespace character handling of html elements.

```html
<h2>
  I am a too long title and i proc a error
</h2>

<!-- inside a pre element: -->
<pre>
I am a too long title and i proc a error</pre
>
```

Comment: For information, the needed result is to use it in 'strict' mode.
But prettier will not reformat and collapse balise and text to avoid white space.

So you need to, manually collapse the text and balise and auto format will work. If someone have another solution it is welcome!